# How can I insert a file into another file when using the Spyder IDE?

Tags: spyder

When editing a file using the Spyder IDE editor I want to add the contents of another file, similar to what Emacs ctrl-x i does. For example:

main.py

```
import sys
def main():
    help_text = """ ### external file contents go here ###"""
    print(help_text)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

insertme.txt

```
Help text someone else gave me.
```

My desired result is a main.py looking like below (after file insertion and a little clean up):

```
import sys
def main():
    help_text = """Help text someone else gave me."""
    print(help_text)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Going through help, online searches, etc. I can't find any direct way to do this (obviously I can do it other ways, but they are more time consuming). Is something like this directly possible with Spyder? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is not possible in our editor, sorry.